# Is there a clean way to to transform text files that are not the same into a standard format

Tags: java, xml, xslt, text-files, text-parsing

I'm pretty sure the answer i'm going to get is: "why don't you just have the text files all be the same or follow some set format". Unfortunately i do not have this option but, i was wondering if there is a way to take any text file and translate it over to another text or xml file that will always look the same?

The text files pretty much have the same data just arranged differently.

The closest i can come up with is to have an XSLT sheet for each text file but, then i have to turn around and read the file that was just created, delete it, and repeat for each text file.

So, is there a way to grab the data off text files that essentially have the same data just stored differently; and store this data in an object that i could then re-use later on in some process?

If it was up to me, i would push for every text file to follow some predefined format since they all pretty much contain the same data but, it's not up to me.

Comment: The answer is yes, mostly, but the precise answer for your case will of course depend on what the input looks like and what formatted output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Odd question... You say they are text files yet mention XSLT as a possible solution. XSLT will only work if the source is XML, if that is so, please redefine the question. If you say text files I assume delimiter separated (e.g. csv), fixed length,...

There are some parsers (like smooks) out there that allow you to parse multiple formats, but it will still require you to perform the "mapping" yourself of course.

This is a typical problem in the integration world so any integration tool should offer you a solution (e.g. wso2, fuse,...).